# Is there a Plastic Barb to PVC Pipe pipe fitting?

Tags: water, pipe, pvc, pump, fitting

I'm using this Diaphragm Pump that I bought online for a certain project, and I want to attach the inlet and outlets of this diaphragm pump to a PVC pipe.

[image]

I think that Barb Outlets are supposed to be used with quick connectors to hoses, but I really need this pump to be used and connected with a PVC pipe.

I searched online and I can't find a quick connect pvc coupling pipe fitting.

Is there such thing as a quick connect pvc coupling pipe fitting?
and if there is, is there a correct way to call it?

If there is no such thing as a quick connect pvc coupling pipe fitting, what is the best way I can do to attach the inlet and outlet to a 1/2 inch PVC pipe and not have leaks?

All suggestions and corrections are highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget hose clamps. Also, the pump may vibrate a bit so fix it firmly to something solid.

Comment: yes thanks for the advise :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the hose barb fittings on a pump or device are removable so you can swap them for another fitting that suits your use. Here, it looks like the hose barbs are molded into the plastic of the pump housing.

For this you can use a short length of vinyl or silicone tubing and a hose barb-PVC fitting of the proper size (shown here). You'd have a few inches of tubing connecting the pump's hose barb and the PVC's hose barb, then run the PVC you need from that.

[image]

Comment: As an added bonus, the hose will absorb any vibration from the pump and not transmit the vibration directly to the PVC which would act as a sounding board and transmit the noise all along the pipe's run.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to find **Barb to Pipe thread** and **Pipe thread to PVC** connectors than a direct transition. You'll still need a short section of hose and hose clamps on the barbed part of the fittings.

Comment: This is a good option if a Barb to PVC connector cannot be found. It's always good to go to the store with an open mind that more than one adapter may be necessary. I've found that when I'm getting to 3 adapters to make the connection, it may be time to rethink the whole plan. :)

Comment: thanks, thats what im going to do :)